# ASP.Net MVC - Update default project reference bundle using Nuget

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, nuget, nuget-package

I'm new with ASP.NET MVC 4 moving from Java framework and just started using NuGet Package Manager to update my reference.

After creating 1 project and updated the reference library such as **Jquery** and **JqueryUi** , I tried to create another project, I thought when I did update my reference in previous project it will be using latest **Jquery** and **JqueryUi** library but it is not so I need to update again.

Is there a way to update my bundle reference package? So when I create new project all my new project have the latest update of reference lib.

Comment: NuGet can't just assume that it can update old versions to the newest, as code may depend on a specific version of the package.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not how the NuGet system works. It is per project.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new project in Visual Studio, it copies the version of the nuget packages that the template was created with.  It's possible to update that template with newer versions, but you cannot get the template to install whatever random version you happen to have installed in other projects in the solution.

As Darin says, NuGet tracks packages on a per project basis.  Honestly, how hard is it to spend the 30 seconds to update to whatever version of the packages you want?  It probably took you longer to write this question than you will ever spend upgrading packages in your lifetime.  So it seems you are at a net time loss ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](http://www.xavierdecoster.com/update-project-template-to-latest-nuget-packages), hope it will help the others too :D